# USB tethering from Ubuntu to Android via USB

Tags: usb, 12.10, android, tethering

I have an Ubuntu 12.10 system on my PC and an Android 4.1 system on my Galaxy Nexus. Now I would like to share the Internet connection of my PC via USB with my Phone. I have been searching with Google a lot, but I only found answers how you can share the Internet connection of the Phone with the PC, but I want it the other way around.

Comment: Looks like a 12.10 bug, see here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2028250

Comment: @DanielPass, seems like you didn't understood the question, author is talking about opposite, tethering *from* computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. But if you have a rooted Android, there is a trick, it's called *Reverse USB tethering*. Check out [this article](http://www.linuxreaders.com/2011/03/android-access-internet-from-computer-via-usb.html), author did that on Fedora, but I guess there should be no problems achieving the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: link is broken and on a 15.10 not working either :-(

Answer (score 0):

A working solution for me on Kubuntu 15.10 & Android 4.2.2 was following

### Requirements

#### Android

1. busybox app installed
2. USB cable to your computer
3. USB Debugging enabled on your android device (to be able to adb from your pc)

#### Computer

1. In your /etc/network/interfaces you need to have these two lines otherwise you'll get a `no such device` error

   ```
   allow-hotplug usb0
   auto usb0
   ```
2. adb installed (`apt-get install android-tools-adb`)

### Connection

1. In your android, enable the Settings->Connections->Network connections->Tethering and portable hotspot->USB tethering option, this will create an USB connection to your computer which you can see with `ifconfig` command on your computer. Look @ the interface name which for me is `enxf6759e7fbebd` this time.

   ```
   enxf6759e7fbebd Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a2:61:3c:83:1c:38  
       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
       RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
       RX bytes:464 (464.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:e5:49:47:f4:fd  
       inet addr:192.168.178.20  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
       RX packets:40894966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:86312833 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
       RX bytes:20969506400 (20.9 GB)  TX bytes:120329513606 (120.3 GB)

   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
       RX packets:30521 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:30521 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
       RX bytes:10868749 (10.8 MB)  TX bytes:10868749 (10.8 MB)
   ```
2. Assign an IP address to your computer on this network interface with following command `sudo ifconfig enxf6759e7fbebd 192.168.42.135 netmask 255.255.255.0` where enxf6759e7fbebd is the interface you got on previous step.
3. Enable IP forwaring with

   ```
   sudo -- sh -c  'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
   ```
4. Enable nat on your computer with

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -F
   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
   ```
5. On your computer connect to your android device with

   ```
   adb shell
   su
   ```
6. then already having your connection you can check with `busybox ifconfig -a` command

   ```
   rndis0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FA:08:D6:1A:35:90  
       inet addr:192.168.42.129  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
       inet6 addr: fe80::f808:d6ff:fe1a:3590/64 Scope:Link
       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
       RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
       RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:564 (564.0 B)
   ```

you can add default route to your computers network address you fixed in point 2 with `busybox route add default gw 192.168.42.135 dev rndis0` and that's it (you can check your routes with `busybox route` command)

### Script

I did a script that I run after enabling the USB Tethering option (point 1 above) that does the work for me

```
#!/bin/bash
interfaceName=$(ifconfig|grep enx|awk '{print $1}') #Getting interface name
sudo ifconfig $interfaceName 192.168.42.135 netmask 255.255.255.0 # setting Computer IP Address
sudo -- sh -c  'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward' # Enabling IP Forwarding 
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
adb shell "su -c 'busybox route add default gw 192.168.42.135 dev rndis0'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a great tool https://github.com/vvviperrr/SimpleRT.
It is quite simple to use and does not require root permissions on your phone.

I tested SimpleRT using Sony Z3 Compact and Ubuntu 16.10 installed on laptop.

The steps are following:

1. Install APK provided on SimpleRT
2. Clone SimpleRT Git repo, or just chose "Download ZIP"
3. Find your active Internet interface using terminal:

   ```
   route | grep '^default' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
   ```
4. Replace in simple-rt-cli/iface_up.sh LOCAL_INTERFACE value from command above.
5. Type "make" in simple-rt-cli directory.
6. Run terminal as root and start CLI:

   ```
   ./simple-rt
   ```
7. Connect your phone using USB cable

Issues (taken from the official page): Some apps do not recognize the reverse tethered internet connection due to ConnectivityManager policy. Just leave WiFi or 3g connection active, connection will go through SimpleRT anyway.

Comment: Could you explain installation and usage in your answer, please?