# Ubuntu-touch reverse USB tethering

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4, reverse-tethering

I'm trying to get the internet from my `Nexus 4 ubuntu-touch` through the USB as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android_Tethering  (this is for Android).

What I cannot accomplish is to see the USB as a network using `ifconfig -a`.

Do I need to enable something on the Ubuntu-Touch for this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/607073/tetherings-not-running-in-ubuntu-touch-how-to-solve-it which mentions Nexus 4 bug, also look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/575171/is-there-or-will-be-a-tethering-access-point-option-in-ubuntu-phone

Comment: Maybe this will work: http://linuxg.net/ubuntu-touch-received-official-support-for-usb-tethering-see-how-to-enable-the-feature/

Comment: maybe this could help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/246604/usb-tethering-from-ubuntu-to-android

Answer (score 1):

Try `ip link` , you'll get a list of interfaces . Check the screenshot , the highlighted interface is the interface for USB tethering [Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y00T1.png)

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.  Please do not attach screenshots but copy/paste the relevant information.