# Is there (or will be) a tethering/access point option in ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, wireless-access-point, tethering

Using ubuntu phone for my daily stuff now since near 2 months on nexus 4, currently on release 165.

I would like to create an access point with my uphone to connect my laptop with, but yet I don't see any option to make this happen.

Is this feature available or officially planned or is there a CLI hack to manage this?

Anyway, I would like to see some changelog or roadmap on the releases, so I am able to Test newly implemented features and/or bugs.

Answer (score 3):

There is support for USB tethering, meaning you have to connect the phone to your PC with an USB cable to access the internet. You can enable USB tethering by entering

```
android-gadget-service enable rndis
```

in Terminal. This will disable MTP (USB file access). You can re-enable MTP by entering

```
android-gadget-service enable mtp
```

From what I've read, USB tethering should "Just Work" with Windows and Ubuntu machines.

There is no UI that I know of for controlling USB or WiFi tethering.

Comment: One small note: it seems that enabling tethering prevents the music application from finding any music (it probably depends on mtp). Just keep that in mind :)

Comment: What about `tethering enable`/ `tethering disable`? Sounds like this could work, too.

Comment: Somehow I can't figure out how to make tethering work. In every tutorial there is the same short command that reportedly does work, only I only watch futile attempts to connect from my laptop. With Android on it before it did work.

Comment: If you have a Nexus 4: There is a bug preventing USB tethering from working on that device: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus-property-service/+bug/1427697