# Tethering's not running in ubuntu-touch, how to solve it?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

My platform:

google nexus 4 ubuntu-touch stable.

Laptop: Ubuntu 14.04.2

I've performed in ubuntu-touch terminal:

> android-gadget-service enable rndis

From the app-indicator of my desktop, I can see the sign of connection is in progress. But, It's just like that, never had a successful connection.
Could you help to solve it? Is there some missing, and how to check?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mako-specific bug (mako: Nexus 4) right now which needs to be fixed. It seems you are affected by this bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus-property-service/+bug/1427697

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't already found it the fix is here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus-property-service/+bug/1427697

Instructions from that link...

Prerequisites for your phone:

- Turn on developer mode: "System settings" | "About this phone" | "Developer mode"
- Make the OS image writable by entering on external computer connected via USB:

  ```
  phablet-config writable-image
  ```
- Make sure that WLAN is turned off.

Steps for fixing tethering (only needed once; repeat after a phone update)

1. unplug the USB cable (on phone side suffices);

   2015-10-15: it seems to have changed now: you must be connected already
2. correct in `/usr/bin/tethering`:

   `rndis0` should be `usb0`
3. enable rndis:

   ```
   sudo android-gadget-service enable rndis
   ```
4. enable tethering:

   ```
   sudo tethering enable
   ```

   Note: this might print an error, which can be ignored.
5. If not done before, plug in the USB cable and the computer connects to the internet using a new wired connection.

Instead of steps 2.-4., you can use a script named `fix-tethering` on your phone:

> sh fix-tethering

The file fix-tethering should contain the following 4 lines:

```
#!
sudo sed -i -e 's/rndis0/usb0/g' /usr/bin/tethering
sudo android-gadget-service enable rndis
sudo tethering enable
```

Comment: I get this after your fix `Device "usb0" does not exist.`

Comment: @nmz787 apparently some devices called the interface `usb0` instead of `rndis0`. This interface appears to be created with `android-gadget-service enable rndis`. As of now it appears this device is _not_ created for some reason